# NestJS Interceptor with async method in controller

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, nestjs, interceptor

I need to intercept the result ( and errors if ther is any ) of a method in a controller throught an interceptor.
The method is asynchronous.

When I throw an error, my interceptor is aware and can do some logic. But when everything is OK, I cant get my interceptor to know it's OK, and do some logic too.

Here is my controller method:

```js
@UseInterceptors(GatewayInterceptor)
@Get([ ':id?', ':id/relationships/:type', 'relationships/:type' ])
public async handleGet(
    @Req()              req             : Request,
    @Res()              res             : Response,
) {
    await this.gatewayService.redirect_to_database_service_GET()
    .then( data => res.send(data))
    .catch(err => {  throw( new HttpException( err.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) ) })
}
```

And the interceptor :

```js
export class GatewayInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

public  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {

  const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

   return next
     .handle()
     .pipe(
      tap( () => { 
       console.log('VALUE')
       this.decrement_user_acces_on_service(request)
      }),
      catchError(error => {
       console.log('ERROR')
       throw error
      })
     );
   }
}
```

the console.log('ERROR') is fired with errors, but I cannot get console.log('VALUE') when everything is OK.

Does someone know where is my error ?

Thanks to anyone who can help me !

Answer (score 0):

OK, my bad, there was an error in my controller:

Await this. GatewayService. redirect_to_database_service_GET (). Then (data => res. send (data))

wasn't resolving any data, so it wouldn't work.

No its ok, and my interceptor can know when there are errors or when it can process data.

Anyway, it could be useful for someone.